# visual studio tooling for mvc in asp.net website project

Tags: model-view-controller, tooling

Can anyone help me. I could not find a solution to enable visual studio mvc templates in a asp.net web site project(not a asp.net web application project). I know that in a asp.net web application project is possible, but for asp.net web site project i havent found a solution.

Can anyone help me.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

MVC is designed to be a Web Application. There are no Microsoft templates for an MVC 'Web site'. Overall IMHO the benefits of a website are not worth the features you lose.

Here is an article provided by MSDN that explains the different features of each : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

To answer your question directly though. MVC asp.net must be a web application.